# ExpressJS Object PUT,DELETE has no method 'toLowerCase'

Tags: javascript, object, express, pug

When I'm attempting to do a PUT request in Express, it gives me that error and I'm not really sure what it means.

This is my jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    form(method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].id}", id="mealForm")
        input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")

        h4 Meal Type
        input.span3(id="mealType", type="text", name="MealType", value="#{meal[0].meal_type}")

        br 

        h4 Meal Details
        input.span3(id="mealDetails", type="text", name="MealDetails", value="#{meal[0].meal_details}")

        br

        input.btn(type="submit", class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Update")

        form(method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].meal_id}", id="mealForm")
            input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="DELETE")

            input.btn(type="submit", class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style='margin-left: 1px;' value="Delete")
```

I don't see why this wouldn't work. This is my app.js:

```
app.put('/meals/:id', meal.getMeal)
```

In meals.js

```
exports.getMeal = function(req, res){
  console.log('sa')
  id = req.params.id

  query = "Select * \
      From nutrition \
      Where id=%"

  query = query.replace(/%/g, id)

  db.query(query, function(err, row) {
        console.log(query);
        if (err) console.log(err)
        res.render('edit', { meal: row });
})
}
```

Stack trace:

```
500 TypeError: Object PUT,DELETE has no method 'toLowerCase'
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:30)
```

Comment: Post your ExpressJS configuration code

Comment: Start by using `var` before each new variable (like `id` and `query`).

Comment: query is a global variable. I'll put it on id. @hilarudeens I'm not sure what file you mean, but I posted the package.json for express http://jsfiddle.net/aUDuL/

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: I figured out what is wrong. Apparently you can't have 2 forms with hidden fields because it then sends an array of objects instead of just PUT/DELETE. Any idea how I can have both in 1?

Comment: @user2417731 Good Catch, So I can guess, your both of the form using same action url. This is the problem, this will leads to try to execute method "put,delete" in your "app" object. In otherwords, it is the form submission looking for handler something as follows " app["put,delete"]('/meals/:id', meal.getMeal) ". This is not possible in express until rewrite the core modules of express js. So my suggestion is either avoid nested form or use different action url.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you nest your HTML forms in the Jade template.
What you basically do is this:

```
<form method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].id}" id="mealForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  <form method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].meal_id}" id="mealForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  </form>
</form>
```

Forms can't be nested. You can have more of them on one page but they must not overlap or nest. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].id}" id="mealForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
<form method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].meal_id}" id="mealForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

The side effect of your code is that it's then send to an Express as array ["PUT", "DELETE"] (because you have two _method fields in your form - the second nested form is ignored) instead of just "PUT" or "DELETE". Express tries to convert received method to lower case for comparison but Array does not have method toLowerCase that String does.

You probably just need to fix your Jade template indent like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    form(method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].id}", id="mealForm")
        input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")

        h4 Meal Type
        input.span3(id="mealType", type="text", name="MealType", value="#{meal[0].meal_type}")

        br 

        h4 Meal Details
        input.span3(id="mealDetails", type="text", name="MealDetails", value="#{meal[0].meal_details}")

        br

        input.btn(type="submit", class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Update")

    form(method="post" action="/meals/#{meal[0].meal_id}", id="mealForm")
        input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="DELETE")

        input.btn(type="submit", class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style='margin-left: 1px;' value="Delete")
```